# How to perfectly separate hemp hearts from hemp seeds

Tags: seeds

I often buy shelled hemp seeds, but there is still a lot of hull in the bought
product. No manufacturer sell hemp seeds perfectly shelled (only hemp hearts).
You can see the typical product on the picture.

[image]

Could you recommend some home-made easy method how to filter (or separate) the hemp hearts (white on the picture) from the hemp hulls (green and black on the picture)?

Comment: It looks like there's at least one manufacturer that sells hearts only : http://smile.amazon.com/dp/B00AR82UNA/

Answer (score 6):

Dry? If so, rolling down an inclined plane, such as a big handheld cutting board into a washing tub should work. The rounder seeds will roll, while the husks remain stuck. Pour in a thin steady stream. Broken seeds will likely still roll, as they've still got bounce to them, while the hulls do not.

Wet? Stirred flotation is likely your best option. Hulls have a larger surface area to mass ratio, so you can stir them right over the sides of a pot with water running into it.

Neither method will give you 100%. To approach that, you need to repeat the process.

Comment: This is easy to say, but can you post pictures of videos about your success?

Comment: Nope. I haven't done it with hemp seed. However one or the other technique works for oats, sunflowers, garbanzos, Bok choy seeds, etc. etc. They're fairly standard separation processes in the food industry in cases where sieving won't do the job. They work fine at home for moderate sized batches, but if you're talking 50Lbs or something, it's time to search the old patent literature to find out how they did these things in say 1883. Many of those old techniques are easily adaptable to medium scale in the modern day.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger : some of them used 'shake tables' with groves in them to catch one of the items, so you could separate things out.  There's also winnowing by wind : a tarp is spread out on the floor of a barn, and doors opened on either end to allow air flow.  Grain is then poured from the upper level onto the tarp, with the less dense items being blown further from the heavier items.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winnowing

Comment: @Joe I actually tried making one of those shake tables with grooves for separating oat groats vs oat groats with hull attached. No joy at a scale you can reasonably expect to build in your basement. I've got a bigger variable speed fan now, and may try the wind method on oats to better success soon. A fan and a sheet for winnowing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winnowing might work nicely for hemp seed. That's best done *outdoors*.

Answer (score 0):

We can easily remove the skin of black gram.

Soak it for long hrs like 5 to 8hrs.

6 hrs is enough.

wash them no of times like we wash rice.

Mix them with hands & just rub them while mixing

same as rice washing.

do it no of times, then it will go

u can find just 5, 6 black skins.

That u can remove by hand.

Comment: Thank your for the answer. Do you think like this? http://youtu.be/cUmHQtiaaoQ I will give it a try, but wonder if only hemp hearts will remain.

Comment: yes.. south indian food idly. liquid preparation method. so many times try this same way.

Comment: This does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing a study on the effects of supplementing quail feed with hemp seed, looking at the nutritional and behavioral benefits on the meat, eggs, and social interaction of the covey.

Quail are a gamebird with small sharp bills suitable for foraging for seed and bugs in the wild.  Natural hemp seed has little if any THC as that is a product of the plant found in high concentration of the oily buds to promote fertilization.  Although the husk is not the source of the hemp nutrients, some husk adds dietary fiber.  On small gamebirds such as quail, chukkar, dove, offering natural whole hemp seed is not harmful.  Cracked hemp seed is a solution that allows the quail a choice of what parts of the seed to enjoy.  Quail hearts, while offering the most nutritional part of the hemp seed are more costly and therefore may not be the ultimate solution to add hemp seed to a commercial product.
To separate a large portion (%25+/_) of hemp shell a combination of a shake table and variable speed fan to remove the obvious husk as well as to identify uncracked seed from the mixture.
For our study, we use an electric vibration table from a 1970's football game (NFL Monday Night) that move the game pieces (team players) when the vibration mechanism is switched on.  With a properly placed vortex desk fan (of hand held personal propeller fan) we can easily remove %75 of the husk pieces from hemp seed we crack in a morter/pestle.  This allows the quail to chose his treat.  Who knows better what the shell nutrients are that the quail?